# lan card doesn't finds my ssid network name

Tags: wifi

I currently use my ethernet cable to connect my Pi to the network. From there I ssh to my Pi and use a VNC client to set up my wireless card.

I click Menu > Preferences > WiFi Configuration and I get as an adapter wlan0 . The problem is I don't see my wireless network when I scan for networks.

Appreciate any help. 
Thank you

Comment: Since the rPi does not come with a WiFi card - can you give us more details on which WiFi dongle you use? Have you done an 'lsusb' and does the WiFi card show up in the output of that command?